# Plot polyline in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-directions-api

I'm exploring Google Maps Direction API and noticed I get an `overview_polyline` -> `points` result. I was able to enter that value in the "Encoded Polyline" field here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility. The result seems to be the actual driving directions from start location to end location. The data looks right to me.

I'd like to see this in a Google Map, but without all the map markers in between the start and end locations. How do I take this information and plot it on Google Maps?

Answer (score 12):

From the Google Maps Javascript API Developers Guide: [Geometry Library: Geometry Encoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Encoding)

> To decode an encoded path, simply call [decodePath()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#encoding) passing the method the encoded string.

The caveat, is beware of backslash encoding (replace any occurrences in your encoded path string of "\\" with "\" if you have problems)

[example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dts67ran/)

code snippet:

```js
var map;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(34, 108),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

  var jsonData = {
    "overview_polyline": {
      "points": "e`miGhmocNaN~DiBiNe@gEkEek@kNez@cJqq@sk@pGos@v]_}@aF_y@qm@qDe~@w]g~@gZ_Jo_@m_@yNsFgUpMov@~QebBrJq`BjTsx@w@kOqbEq_@qkCcf@}}Dej@yzCuf@o{Ba]m~EtVewAnBa`@sNmm@}dDufGqwA_|D_z@g~CmtBkuOrBmtCyG_yCam@{`Ee]qkB}d@ucDmDe|Aha@e}At]{v@xD}e@yf@aeIm^{rEgp@ahBiZu`BkVueH}gDwuXu`Fi__@yZecHgoAgyIl[ybCo^sgD_n@akBaJmeBog@yyAe`@ayB~FifCjNkmAzTwpAgf@cpFy~@{lJsg@ojHyi@e_Fq}@o`Dog@}tBoYmz@y`@sf@qf@ohCkLugBuv@seAg[ul@mMowBqc@iiC}eAcwCqm@_fBmuAypFyIiqA}BwyBy`@ogAwt@ypBezC{dIahBwxJgb@ytCw~AwvJkQwu@{t@yrCg{@s{Fgb@ehDzKsdAxO}vAiRmpCwcAorNuwAgdS_r@imJq[orAk]wrA_TyzAnFefAa\\guB_OmwAwF{tCwMcbDcr@m}_@}Qo_RgMo|A|d@kpAne@u{Brb@wnDzNkuB_D{v@eSgf@w\\ieAyb@guCii@ifCga@i_Amc@m]urAyoD}o@kiIsr@opQuLkhAc_@q`Bq\\}bEeEyi@iE}t@pHi|@tBmlBebB{qHq_BinFoWgpBoDuqEob@k{ConAedC}L}h@yd@yfAgz@}gAaZi_@m}@mcBwyAaj@_bBg|@csBm_Bo|BkaC{iBqsB_YqyBxEmtBks@aoB{RgLa~@bCcr@cLyoAemBeg@gt@_}@e`@on@uu@etA}vCqp@ubAklDgeGmxFiqHaqFoeHa[wbBu]}gAuoDeeG{uAooB_uAsy@om@ugAu_L{xSshEe_KieDm|KcfIcuWeUcOwy@aP{QuUg`BipF{P_l@klAgaEmjEs}NsvAiyFs}@izFjwAqrGtHkbCeB{cEql@g~CgSk|@mB}oAqNekEgw@cmDo_BgjFqqC}gH}`CwvG}cA{cB}nFowQ_t@an@efBmpE_oAsvCka@mwBk_CqbGuu@qfB{uAmrDivDw|E{nAqbDmpCyaJgdCejHk~@owAsw@adAm_@abA}Ven@qCou@cKeiBca@_cBmlAyjAsn@_kCk}@smDkVg{Bk}@gcHox@_sEaPwdC~KazF{EcpCrEmeGl]auBeEi~@yiAovCwwAgsC{i@oSsbAu~Ay_AmaBk_@iKak@mh@_BmBk@wHvG@dBvA"
    }
  };
  var path = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(jsonData.overview_polyline.points);
  console.log(path);
  for (var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(path[i]);
  }

  var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: path,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: map
      // strokeColor: "#0000FF",
      // strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      // strokeWeight: 2
  });
  polyline.setMap(map);
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Comment: If this answered your question, please [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)