# Google Maps Decode Path (Polyline) - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have problem with decoding string to function from Google Maps. I have error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL.

I don't know what I should to do. Maybe problem is tilde in text ? (`)  Please help me with this.

When I copy this string to function on [Google Maps website](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility),everything is ok.

```
var decodedPath = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath("i|ftHkwjlBCEF]HNVjA`@nA\hA`@nAD`ABt@Bz@Zf@b@Zn@^x@\|@PbAPbADx@DrAEpAUtAk@lAcAjA_AzAe@pAm@lA_AbAcB`AmBx@iBl@eBr@qBd@{BX}BXsBTqBu@QJk@h@cAJiBBmBFwAKyA@}@DA@A???????????@AFANAl@Bn@@d@EbAChAGxAQdBa@r@_@d@JH`@Lh@Td@Rh@Tr@Xr@Zj@T`@f@PxA~@hBjAt@fAH|@\xASx@eB\uAn@t@~@bA~@l@jB~@nAh@nAh@pAp@jA~@x@hAz@lAv@d@t@e@|@q@lA}@nBeBjAcAz@u@`Aq@|@u@hAaAhAeAv@k@^b@\pA^xA^vAVhAb@zAVrA]V{@Xy@d@k@\s@b@q@`@o@\m@XeAj@gAj@gAd@aAh@{@l@u@n@{@l@m@f@y@j@m@f@m@d@mA`Ak@h@u@j@k@b@m@b@s@f@k@\q@h@i@^q@d@[RGD@A@E@CCB@?@DA??????????????E?GAB?FCA?@@@BBZWh@a@b@WJE?AA?????????????????????RS`Aq@fA{@|@q@bAy@bAy@rAeArAiApAcAtAeAtAeArAu@vAo@~@i@t@g@jAg@lAq@hAm@~@k@hAYDiB_@aBc@aBg@eBYqAi@yAcAl@qAjAeAh@}@[}AV}B\wAb@aAVeArAiAtAeAT_AA}@EoAe@cA]aAg@mAo@iAk@iAs@aAiAeAi@]`A[bAk@~@y@Ew@]eAO}@Ku@kAy@kAC_Be@Ww@Wy@_@}@a@u@[y@[[YCyAFqB_@eB@oAh@}@RaAWu@PcB`@iA^kAj@yA`@gAr@{Al@oAN_Bf@c@j@m@bAeAhAsA|@w@`As@~@s@hAq@fAQz@c@jBy@jAU|@YjAa@bAMvAIrACrAH`ALbAJpAZnALdAHdAF`AKjAIr@~@bA\x@VjAGjAKfAUz@c@|@[Zk@s@A@i@j@_Ab@o@z@m@~@m@b@iAZiAp@s@r@k@pAiAz@s@`Aa@jAu@dAw@|@mAp@gAp@}Av@eAf@eAd@aAVgAQqAg@y@a@k@[c@Y[c@a@Yg@Y}@Wo@]_@[Cu@Xi@Mc@Kc@d@w@lAi@`B{@rAQl@ADHAH@A@?EEAKIJSV_@V]Pi@Rg@Lm@Pa@V]TWX[VO`@Cd@@l@Cp@Zd@dA\bAHd@Wt@c@Pq@JE`AOt@CD???@????@?AAAC????IFCH???C?CCOCOB@??@?????@LLB?@A??@BA@BA?B?HQDg@Aq@Ne@XCf@AZk@JUGOYy@a@gAc@e@k@e@m@e@k@k@o@w@w@}@{@_Ay@eAgAgA_AcAg@o@OK{@n@mA\eAGcA?kAGkAQ}@Q}@QaAQmASgAJ_Ap@cAv@a@tAQdBq@rAkAf@aAb@{@b@kA`A_A|@{@z@o@eAWgAImAAkBCsBE}AGkBCsAE}AGM?G?@?BA????@??@AA???@?@???@A??A??@??@CAA@A?A@????GDk@IiACqAIqACeAEsAJo@h@Op@St@Od@IVSLk@CkAEsAEuACoAAO??????????Cg@Ak@GyACwACuACoA@uAAyAEmAA{Aa@y@u@m@]]^}@v@{@x@u@`Ae@^iAGuC]gBYcBSkBGoBBkBGoBWeBWyASkBSmB]gC]eA]DJ{@X_BVyAVwAVuAXwAVqAVyAZqBRkB\iBToAUkAa@{Ag@e@q@@e@LWJk@Rs@Rs@Ti@Da@LQHa@Lm@Pu@Tm@Tm@XUJCBb@Or@_@t@]p@Uv@Ul@UBKA?AEAGCICYN{@P_AG}@Su@]QA@CCCS@C?@@E?C?A@?AA@A?AAA@A??@??@??A??@??????A??@?A????A@@?@AA@???A???A????@@?A?????@B@??@@@X?B?CA@@@???@??A???A?A@@????CA?????ALX^`@|@MhAWjAHb@DDBLh@H~Ag@~@Y~@Y`AP`@lAZnA\N\gBf@eCf@iCd@eC`@qB^oB^oBd@aCf@gCd@eCb@}Bd@cC`@aCb@aCd@_Cf@_Ch@{Bh@}Bb@cBn@{Bl@wBn@{Bn@{Bn@aCf@kBj@kBn@{BnAkEl@wBn@{Bn@}Br@cCp@yBr@wBr@qBr@qBl@iBl@HVzARtA^pA\nAp@v@l@vAt@_@~@Oz@Lt@Hn@Ff@RXp@NrA`@r@r@z@x@bAv@dA|@z@fAThAPz@N`AJ|APjAUbAa@jAa@z@m@@eAu@}@u@iAi@}@]iBWwAYcDG}Ah@}@\}@^s@f@i@h@i@h@a@f@s@d@y@f@w@p@e@b@g@j@o@h@}@p@m@f@eAr@Yx@]z@_@l@Qf@|@Hz@Kn@Qb@]^m@h@k@VCB??GBOJEF?A@E?CA?@@@?A@TSB??@??BEPAl@_@r@u@ZkAVc@x@ZlAl@v@WLqBf@aAdAW|@IhAIdAOb@t@\dAPbAj@JNc@YoA]iB]iBWuA]cB?cAz@_@`Ak@x@a@dA[jAWjAc@jAk@nAi@jAk@`A[nAg@~@e@`Ac@jAi@~@e@rB_AlAe@rAm@rAa@pA]rAa@pA_@p@FTfBNxBd@^v@g@bAo@fAm@dAm@z@c@jAK~@?~@@bAKNoAJgBJmBJqBLsBHmBFiBLmBJ}AJsBJ{ARoBJwAJgBRaCPiBLyAViB\qBVqBXkBXmBXkBXkBXoB`@uCVqBXoBVmBVeBXeBVkBReBRyAVkBRwA\}BVgBXkBVcBZiBVgBRsATgBJiBJeB@uABmCAsA@}AAiBHcBBkBAoB@}ACW@C?@????????????@D?A@@BA@A??@@??AA??@@A@@EAA@B?C?GC_@Cq@?qA@gA@u@?K?A????AOBgADqABsAI[UAM@MBI?Y@c@?i@@e@@s@Ay@A{@@}@?aA?_AHcACw@?{@@s@@aAGg@?I@EBS?[?m@@}@Ew@FaA@eAD_AAmBG}@HeAGaAC}@@w@?o@@]?CA@?DG?aA?cACoAF_B?yAEmA@oAC_AEqAAkA@oAAiABiAGo@?A???@DBA@A?@??A?@@Ae@AaAA{@D_AA_ACo@Fo@Ai@?y@Ao@@o@?qAGmA@cAHo@I_@DW?Q?g@Eq@Bw@HcADsAAcA?uACaABgAAaA@eAAeABcA?_A?aA@aA@cAAy@EcA@_A@cA?_A@aABuA?_A?aA@aA?eAG}@H}@@{@?}@JeABsAOeAF}@CeACw@DaA?s@@gAAcA@q@C_AHq@Dq@?_AL{@K}@KcACeA@aA?cA?_AD_AD_A?cA@cA?eAAeACaAB_AC{@Dk@?i@?u@Bu@?WUCHQb@WDTK^y@^s@\o@BE?????@@CAGAA??????@@AB?GKB@?A?????????Ma@a@}@a@}@g@iAg@eAi@cAi@kAw@aAe@kAg@_Ac@_Ai@iAm@gAw@{AKIk@Ge@aAi@oA_@eAg@oAa@_Ae@cAo@iAi@aAc@eAm@mAm@sAo@uAm@oAUkAb@oAI}Ag@gAm@kAg@sAe@aAk@oAm@kAm@kAc@_Ae@cAe@aAg@_Ag@_Ag@_ATaAd@}@`@eBJmATyARaBToAUoA}@[y@[w@`@u@Xw@@qAEm@o@i@oAk@oAk@sAi@kAm@oAk@sAm@uAm@sAk@qAi@mAi@mAi@kAc@aAc@_Ai@mAa@_Ac@aAk@aAg@m@s@s@o@e@y@k@e@{@EuAGuASeB[_Bg@sAg@mAg@mAe@oAg@qA{@cCc@kAa@gA_@gA[}@_@qAU_A[sAUqAq@k@w@g@eAm@s@g@k@a@q@Yo@Ek@Ps@^q@f@q@h@{@j@cAReBI_AS}@Ou@@m@LYZi@Is@HeANgAGy@]qAo@_Ag@{@k@{@m@_AKe@IRy@ZoAXmA\oA\sAj@iBd@y@r@k@x@c@t@s@PcBDaBB{ADwAEsAA{ACwBJqAMaAq@Ei@Fq@Hw@L}@BgADs@F}@F{@Jw@Hu@Du@F{@BgAD_A@eAJeABy@Jy@JeA@w@@u@L{@Ik@u@i@gAg@eAm@{@c@q@eAi@{@u@w@c@}@Wi@WmAC{@Oo@Rk@^cAb@u@\_AX}@Xi@\_Bj@}@`@_AZm@Zy@V{@j@w@z@q@z@s@~@o@x@o@^w@\_AVw@`@g@^y@Z_APq@Po@^{@X{@Xy@Pw@j@m@p@i@p@c@`Ae@n@BBHZNf@Dt@Jt@Hn@Bj@Fv@Fh@?F?B@@?A?@Fp@LjAL|@FjALfANbAN`AH|@H~@L|@Fv@Dp@H~@Fn@Fl@Fr@Fl@H^@b@?LFH?L?ACEMBC@MCI?MEEA?@CA?C?D@BACAACD?CA???@@?????C?@??OH[Ac@C[HeABa@Le@Ae@De@Bm@Ba@?i@Bi@Fm@Im@F}@Jm@TG|@RvAXvBNzANbBN|AN`ADnALtATzBHrAFvA?vAArBB~B@rBC|BFnB?hBApB@vABlB?nBBlBBpBAlBArB@jB@hB?|A?jB?bBBhCCzA@pB?vB@~A@hBBjB?tB?zBDnBClB@jC?xACpBBdBAtA@bBAfB@zABnAEjBFxAEjBBnBAlA@hBCnB?fBJfBCjB?fBAdBAhBAdBFnBEpADhBBjBT|ATfBPxALlAVnARlANxA\`CDNBB@??A??CAA@@CA???????????????????????BLn@j@j@Tv@f@h@p@^jAl@z@l@t@j@r@n@v@r@z@r@x@jAbBv@x@l@v@n@t@j@v@r@~@x@l@t@t@t@z@p@h@t@h@`A^r@Fv@Pn@hAj@jAj@lAl@nAr@lAj@pAp@fAn@dAn@~@v@pAf@x@f@x@l@~@j@t@j@~@^v@_@~@g@n@o@`Aq@`Ao@~@c@t@c@n@o@p@q@f@u@f@w@b@u@h@m@`@o@\u@h@w@b@eAt@w@d@s@f@q@^y@l@u@d@u@f@g@h@JjA`@nA^pAf@nAd@bAd@x@f@jAb@|@f@dAd@r@t@lAr@fAh@z@p@bAjAvBp@~@r@fAn@jAd@vAVjA\|AXpA\fB^bB`@bBh@~B^`B\bBZ`B\~AXlA\~AXjAZ`BVlAZxAd@~BZ|AZzA\xA\vAVdAXrAV|@Nx@[f@s@c@uAz@m@`@u@l@o@b@m@j@k@h@u@p@q@t@k@n@q@r@m@t@kArAq@b@o@PCv@IL?CA@?@???@?A@?A?@C?@?@??????????????????????ALIJSXU`@]j@U`@Wb@[l@[j@]n@[l@U`@Sd@[l@Wl@Wj@Ub@Sh@[r@g@nAUf@Yn@Un@Yx@Ur@Sl@Qj@Sp@Oh@St@Wx@Sx@Ol@Od@Or@Qr@Qv@Qx@Qt@Q|@Oz@Mp@QbAMt@M|@Mz@Ir@M~@Kr@Ix@Kx@Gj@Kl@Kr@MfAKx@M~@M|@Ov@Kn@Kn@Mx@Ox@Ih@I\BC???ACGBWFe@Ha@Ji@Ho@Jo@Jq@N{@RqAHo@L}@Ju@L{@Hw@Hm@Ho@Ly@L_AJ{@Jw@L_ANeALs@Jm@N{@Lm@Ny@Nw@P{@Nu@Nm@ZoANk@Ru@Rs@Tu@V}@Vw@Tw@Vq@Rm@Pk@Vs@Zu@Zw@Tk@Ve@Xq@Xo@Zq@Vg@Te@Vi@Vg@\o@\m@Xi@Xe@^q@\g@Ta@Xe@X]H]?BEBC??@AA@@??A?A???????@??A@A??CD@G?@???@??????@@?A@@BM@K?A??B??BBA@B??@A?@?A??@????A?@D??AABAA??A@?A?@???A?@A????@A?@AA??@@@????D@CAA????????????????????????????????????A??????@???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????@?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????NNx@M^j@T?@[AA?@?MFC?A?A?????BA@??@???????????????????????????@S?A?????@????????????????@DCHGPGp@Sm@SU]BUNYMSRKR??A@A?????????????????DBRc@XCh@Kd@NVp@Fg@@_@A?BI???@????????????B?A?@AA??@??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????B?F?PW`@c@h@i@h@g@x@w@f@e@d@_@DC??@???A@TUd@_@x@i@~@o@t@c@bAo@z@e@n@_@d@`AZlAd@tBXpAXjATtATnATjAJdALjAN~@PnALbABlAA`@Gp@GdA\`ANbAr@Nx@Ij@y@z@c@z@K~@GzAI`AI`@DFs@b@Kr@Iv@Cr@QbAK`A@dA?dBNr@h@LjANhBNdBNfBLhBN`BLzAN|ATrAn@Ar@_@j@Yv@g@z@c@n@SVjARlAJn@l@[t@c@lAk@\x@N`AN|@RnARhANhARjAPdANt@HZBLA@???LJLZV^X\R\TVR\ZFEYSc@SUW?Hb@\`@\b@^VT??????????????@I_@_@Fw@Pk@`@QT[WTNQK{@SgASaAQo@Q_AO_AKu@G@HLJd@@L?BDRJb@Jf@Nl@Nz@Px@Jr@Nh@f@QRKPOPMRI\Q^S`@Uh@Uh@]RGA??A??A@OJ_@Pg@Vg@Vg@Xi@Zg@V{@^Sy@UmAUmAUgAUmAU_ABe@Pq@T_@J@HBA??@?????@FF@??A?B???AI?EDA@??@E@C???A??@?F?@B@B@??AA?DA?A????F??B???@??@?B?ACSG_@EMX?@ELMb@IZ?LNLH\Hp@Jz@Rn@Nx@RdAP|@?f@BF^W^RPjAPbAPjAPlATtAN`ALx@K|@e@Hm@TEpAJ`BHjBHfBD|AH|AH|ADxAFpBJzAHnADrA@vA?hABzABjAFvAFtADzABlABxAFnAHfA@tA@xADvABrAB~ADxAKdAWn@k@HWz@FnADfAFvADpAHvA?~AHbBn@Pz@E~@El@MHB??AC@I?@?@B@ABA@?@?A???????????B@A?@CCIC]Da@Fg@B_@@g@D_@KIaAEcACkACaAKgBGyAGyAOkAI{@e@Cy@Fq@H_AD_ADw@BkAFm@Cu@ASSCA??[Ba@CS}@KiADq@@A?A??????BUe@[_AFcATaAp@_Ax@iAx@eAl@aAn@eAj@_Ap@u@^{@d@aAj@m@^s@Li@i@k@FWr@QbAi@^o@Zq@v@w@d@o@r@w@b@w@h@{@j@oAt@w@j@u@d@w@d@w@d@w@h@o@d@q@`@o@h@}@l@y@l@iAz@q@j@w@f@u@l@w@j@u@f@y@l@y@j@}@l@aAp@y@t@cA`Am@j@{@n@y@f@{@j@{@n@w@l@y@j@w@l@y@j@{@n@oA|@o@d@o@f@k@b@u@f@i@b@s@f@g@b@s@j@m@d@o@j@e@T]Z]Da@e@c@u@]m@Mq@W?IG??A???GNDn@If@QZC@@AA?EM?A???@??BFA?@@A@@A???????????@B@????AB?AGPUZa@b@k@l@m@p@c@f@o@r@g@f@m@r@q@x@q@x@g@n@q@p@k@j@o@v@e@j@eAlAg@j@q@r@q@r@g@j@q@v@i@l@o@r@m@v@s@v@q@r@mAtAe@l@o@v@i@l@w@x@y@~@{@|@{@`A_AdA_AfAu@rAk@lCGrBFlBHpBJlB?nBMtA[pAm@nAq@dAi@p@oA~As@bAu@bAm@~@a@t@Ph@d@n@j@r@f@n@b@f@h@p@l@v@h@p@d@f@l@d@h@Xj@Tr@Tt@Tt@Tv@Vv@T`Bf@|@Vx@Vv@Tx@Tx@Nx@N~@N~@Hx@Nz@Hb@z@FbBDfBFxAElBUpBSzAYlBa@hBa@fBSrAK`DBrBBpBFpB@tB?pBDdBFrAD\?T???@??B^D`ABRHEJCDDHd@V\Xb@LDA@AACK??A???ACAK?KFA@?AA@B@@@B?@?A@?AG@A???@????????????CDAAAG?ABD?@@@?B?B?????@??@?@?A@????????????@???ACAG?A??AC???@?@?@?B???AAC?@A@@@@??AA????A????B?BA?DAC??D?DA@??????@???????@CB?@??CAE?AA??C?@??@@?@AAA?B?B?B@????AAAEF??ALEA@ADDD@??AA??@?AB??@B?@xWzY\I\Od@Q\Mn@Ut@Yv@Wv@[t@Yv@SpAk@x@Wp@Wh@Ux@Y~@_@`AY`AQ~@Q|@S`AUdAMdAKhAIhAM|@CFlADfBDnBDxADfBHxANzCHzAFnALz@DnAJtA@tAm@`@i@Fk@?_@F]f@WTSh@Q`@a@Vc@\a@HUQQSUU_@Ss@Bg@Ji@Jc@HWFSHODUH[P[Fa@Ha@BW@OJQJYTS^MPCBA?@?????A???@A????@?A@?@????GB@CCBG?GBKF?LFPALQBODSPMNMPKTKNKTGPGXIRGP?RCDENCF?RALGRGTQFQDG@Q?SAQCM@OLGPIPOFOBKAGC?AA?B?DBB?IAB?LEJEHCJCDC@EDOLKJCN@N@PDL?LAJANEBC?Q@S?SBQBSHSBYFWHQDQHSJWJSJOLMJOLMJCJIH?HABA?EEECSDM@?BADEDABAFC@B@?A??????@@B???@AA?@?A@C?AFEJOP]TQTOXMX?ZE`@E^Ob@Qd@Sh@K^I`@G`@Kh@Gj@Zh@h@b@Nn@a@h@c@Zy@f@u@v@Yl@@n@Ob@[?{@GiAGcAEs@G_AIiAIkAGoAIyAG{ACqAEkACkACcAAcAA}@Bo@ZMb@KFCIa@`@?p@Gl@Gl@G|@Il@Gt@Cl@Ar@Ev@Yj@Uf@[l@Ip@Kp@Gr@Lt@Er@Kr@Bl@Dl@Aj@Ol@Qj@Un@_@x@a@t@c@l@a@p@a@`Ac@vA[t@{@^c@BOCSC[Em@Q}@MgAGkAEaALq@b@g@Li@O}@OcAS_AQ_AO{@Mg@@GAGAGEMCE@Gb@SDG?GAGAI?EFEZWd@FZc@XKf@^j@Nf@a@h@a@b@e@^e@`@i@j@k@\]^g@l@u@?_A[m@ST_@r@]p@GD@AC?AC@?@A??@@???????????AAEJIFN@@@@C@?BA??????????????????@C?A@G@C?@A?@?@????????A@?@???CAA?A?@???CBC@???@???A@?A????????????????????????????AICCA?@B?@@@?????????????@????????????????????????????@?AA????????????@@??");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to "double encode" the `\` characters inside the string.  I did a search and replace of `\` with `\\` and it works.

related question: [Plot polyline in Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29481300/plot-polyline-in-google-maps)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
  var decodedPath = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath("i|ftHkwjlBCEF]HNVjA`@nA\\hA`@nAD`ABt@Bz@Zf@b@Zn@^x@\\|@PbAPbADx@DrAEpAUtAk@lAcAjA_AzAe@pAm@lA_AbAcB`AmBx@iBl@eBr@qBd@{BX}BXsBTqBu@QJk@h@cAJiBBmBFwAKyA@}@DA@A???????????@AFANAl@Bn@@d@EbAChAGxAQdBa@r@_@d@JH`@Lh@Td@Rh@Tr@Xr@Zj@T`@f@PxA~@hBjAt@fAH|@\\xASx@eB\\uAn@t@~@bA~@l@jB~@nAh@nAh@pAp@jA~@x@hAz@lAv@d@t@e@|@q@lA}@nBeBjAcAz@u@`Aq@|@u@hAaAhAeAv@k@^b@\\pA^xA^vAVhAb@zAVrA]V{@Xy@d@k@\\s@b@q@`@o@\\m@XeAj@gAj@gAd@aAh@{@l@u@n@{@l@m@f@y@j@m@f@m@d@mA`Ak@h@u@j@k@b@m@b@s@f@k@\\q@h@i@^q@d@[RGD@A@E@CCB@?@DA??????????????E?GAB?FCA?@@@BBZWh@a@b@WJE?AA?????????????????????RS`Aq@fA{@|@q@bAy@bAy@rAeArAiApAcAtAeAtAeArAu@vAo@~@i@t@g@jAg@lAq@hAm@~@k@hAYDiB_@aBc@aBg@eBYqAi@yAcAl@qAjAeAh@}@[}AV}B\\wAb@aAVeArAiAtAeAT_AA}@EoAe@cA]aAg@mAo@iAk@iAs@aAiAeAi@]`A[bAk@~@y@Ew@]eAO}@Ku@kAy@kAC_Be@Ww@Wy@_@}@a@u@[y@[[YCyAFqB_@eB@oAh@}@RaAWu@PcB`@iA^kAj@yA`@gAr@{Al@oAN_Bf@c@j@m@bAeAhAsA|@w@`As@~@s@hAq@fAQz@c@jBy@jAU|@YjAa@bAMvAIrACrAH`ALbAJpAZnALdAHdAF`AKjAIr@~@bA\\x@VjAGjAKfAUz@c@|@[Zk@s@A@i@j@_Ab@o@z@m@~@m@b@iAZiAp@s@r@k@pAiAz@s@`Aa@jAu@dAw@|@mAp@gAp@}Av@eAf@eAd@aAVgAQqAg@y@a@k@[c@Y[c@a@Yg@Y}@Wo@]_@[Cu@Xi@Mc@Kc@d@w@lAi@`B{@rAQl@ADHAH@A@?EEAKIJSV_@V]Pi@Rg@Lm@Pa@V]TWX[VO`@Cd@@l@Cp@Zd@dA\\bAHd@Wt@c@Pq@JE`AOt@CD???@????@?AAAC????IFCH???C?CCOCOB@??@?????@LLB?@A??@BA@BA?B?HQDg@Aq@Ne@XCf@AZk@JUGOYy@a@gAc@e@k@e@m@e@k@k@o@w@w@}@{@_Ay@eAgAgA_AcAg@o@OK{@n@mA\\eAGcA?kAGkAQ}@Q}@QaAQmASgAJ_Ap@cAv@a@tAQdBq@rAkAf@aAb@{@b@kA`A_A|@{@z@o@eAWgAImAAkBCsBE}AGkBCsAE}AGM?G?@?BA????@??@AA???@?@???@A??A??@??@CAA@A?A@????GDk@IiACqAIqACeAEsAJo@h@Op@St@Od@IVSLk@CkAEsAEuACoAAO??????????Cg@Ak@GyACwACuACoA@uAAyAEmAA{Aa@y@u@m@]]^}@v@{@x@u@`Ae@^iAGuC]gBYcBSkBGoBBkBGoBWeBWyASkBSmB]gC]eA]DJ{@X_BVyAVwAVuAXwAVqAVyAZqBRkB\\iBToAUkAa@{Ag@e@q@@e@LWJk@Rs@Rs@Ti@Da@LQHa@Lm@Pu@Tm@Tm@XUJCBb@Or@_@t@]p@Uv@Ul@UBKA?AEAGCICYN{@P_AG}@Su@]QA@CCCS@C?@@E?C?A@?AA@A?AAA@A??@??@??A??@??????A??@?A????A@@?@AA@???A???A????@@?A?????@B@??@@@X?B?CA@@@???@??A???A?A@@????CA?????ALX^`@|@MhAWjAHb@DDBLh@H~Ag@~@Y~@Y`AP`@lAZnA\\N\\gBf@eCf@iCd@eC`@qB^oB^oBd@aCf@gCd@eCb@}Bd@cC`@aCb@aCd@_Cf@_Ch@{Bh@}Bb@cBn@{Bl@wBn@{Bn@{Bn@aCf@kBj@kBn@{BnAkEl@wBn@{Bn@}Br@cCp@yBr@wBr@qBr@qBl@iBl@HVzARtA^pA\\nAp@v@l@vAt@_@~@Oz@Lt@Hn@Ff@RXp@NrA`@r@r@z@x@bAv@dA|@z@fAThAPz@N`AJ|APjAUbAa@jAa@z@m@@eAu@}@u@iAi@}@]iBWwAYcDG}Ah@}@\\}@^s@f@i@h@i@h@a@f@s@d@y@f@w@p@e@b@g@j@o@h@}@p@m@f@eAr@Yx@]z@_@l@Qf@|@Hz@Kn@Qb@]^m@h@k@VCB??GBOJEF?A@E?CA?@@@?A@TSB??@??BEPAl@_@r@u@ZkAVc@x@ZlAl@v@WLqBf@aAdAW|@IhAIdAOb@t@\\dAPbAj@JNc@YoA]iB]iBWuA]cB?cAz@_@`Ak@x@a@dA[jAWjAc@jAk@nAi@jAk@`A[nAg@~@e@`Ac@jAi@~@e@rB_AlAe@rAm@rAa@pA]rAa@pA_@p@FTfBNxBd@^v@g@bAo@fAm@dAm@z@c@jAK~@?~@@bAKNoAJgBJmBJqBLsBHmBFiBLmBJ}AJsBJ{ARoBJwAJgBRaCPiBLyAViB\\qBVqBXkBXmBXkBXkBXoB`@uCVqBXoBVmBVeBXeBVkBReBRyAVkBRwA\\}BVgBXkBVcBZiBVgBRsATgBJiBJeB@uABmCAsA@}AAiBHcBBkBAoB@}ACW@C?@????????????@D?A@@BA@A??@@??AA??@@A@@EAA@B?C?GC_@Cq@?qA@gA@u@?K?A????AOBgADqABsAI[UAM@MBI?Y@c@?i@@e@@s@Ay@A{@@}@?aA?_AHcACw@?{@@s@@aAGg@?I@EBS?[?m@@}@Ew@FaA@eAD_AAmBG}@HeAGaAC}@@w@?o@@]?CA@?DG?aA?cACoAF_B?yAEmA@oAC_AEqAAkA@oAAiABiAGo@?A???@DBA@A?@??A?@@Ae@AaAA{@D_AA_ACo@Fo@Ai@?y@Ao@@o@?qAGmA@cAHo@I_@DW?Q?g@Eq@Bw@HcADsAAcA?uACaABgAAaA@eAAeABcA?_A?aA@aA@cAAy@EcA@_A@cA?_A@aABuA?_A?aA@aA?eAG}@H}@@{@?}@JeABsAOeAF}@CeACw@DaA?s@@gAAcA@q@C_AHq@Dq@?_AL{@K}@KcACeA@aA?cA?_AD_AD_A?cA@cA?eAAeACaAB_AC{@Dk@?i@?u@Bu@?WUCHQb@WDTK^y@^s@\\o@BE?????@@CAGAA??????@@AB?GKB@?A?????????Ma@a@}@a@}@g@iAg@eAi@cAi@kAw@aAe@kAg@_Ac@_Ai@iAm@gAw@{AKIk@Ge@aAi@oA_@eAg@oAa@_Ae@cAo@iAi@aAc@eAm@mAm@sAo@uAm@oAUkAb@oAI}Ag@gAm@kAg@sAe@aAk@oAm@kAm@kAc@_Ae@cAe@aAg@_Ag@_Ag@_ATaAd@}@`@eBJmATyARaBToAUoA}@[y@[w@`@u@Xw@@qAEm@o@i@oAk@oAk@sAi@kAm@oAk@sAm@uAm@sAk@qAi@mAi@mAi@kAc@aAc@_Ai@mAa@_Ac@aAk@aAg@m@s@s@o@e@y@k@e@{@EuAGuASeB[_Bg@sAg@mAg@mAe@oAg@qA{@cCc@kAa@gA_@gA[}@_@qAU_A[sAUqAq@k@w@g@eAm@s@g@k@a@q@Yo@Ek@Ps@^q@f@q@h@{@j@cAReBI_AS}@Ou@@m@LYZi@Is@HeANgAGy@]qAo@_Ag@{@k@{@m@_AKe@IRy@ZoAXmA\\oA\\sAj@iBd@y@r@k@x@c@t@s@PcBDaBB{ADwAEsAA{ACwBJqAMaAq@Ei@Fq@Hw@L}@BgADs@F}@F{@Jw@Hu@Du@F{@BgAD_A@eAJeABy@Jy@JeA@w@@u@L{@Ik@u@i@gAg@eAm@{@c@q@eAi@{@u@w@c@}@Wi@WmAC{@Oo@Rk@^cAb@u@\\_AX}@Xi@\\_Bj@}@`@_AZm@Zy@V{@j@w@z@q@z@s@~@o@x@o@^w@\\_AVw@`@g@^y@Z_APq@Po@^{@X{@Xy@Pw@j@m@p@i@p@c@`Ae@n@BBHZNf@Dt@Jt@Hn@Bj@Fv@Fh@?F?B@@?A?@Fp@LjAL|@FjALfANbAN`AH|@H~@L|@Fv@Dp@H~@Fn@Fl@Fr@Fl@H^@b@?LFH?L?ACEMBC@MCI?MEEA?@CA?C?D@BACAACD?CA???@@?????C?@??OH[Ac@C[HeABa@Le@Ae@De@Bm@Ba@?i@Bi@Fm@Im@F}@Jm@TG|@RvAXvBNzANbBN|AN`ADnALtATzBHrAFvA?vAArBB~B@rBC|BFnB?hBApB@vABlB?nBBlBBpBAlBArB@jB@hB?|A?jB?bBBhCCzA@pB?vB@~A@hBBjB?tB?zBDnBClB@jC?xACpBBdBAtA@bBAfB@zABnAEjBFxAEjBBnBAlA@hBCnB?fBJfBCjB?fBAdBAhBAdBFnBEpADhBBjBT|ATfBPxALlAVnARlANxA\\`CDNBB@??A??CAA@@CA???????????????????????BLn@j@j@Tv@f@h@p@^jAl@z@l@t@j@r@n@v@r@z@r@x@jAbBv@x@l@v@n@t@j@v@r@~@x@l@t@t@t@z@p@h@t@h@`A^r@Fv@Pn@hAj@jAj@lAl@nAr@lAj@pAp@fAn@dAn@~@v@pAf@x@f@x@l@~@j@t@j@~@^v@_@~@g@n@o@`Aq@`Ao@~@c@t@c@n@o@p@q@f@u@f@w@b@u@h@m@`@o@\\u@h@w@b@eAt@w@d@s@f@q@^y@l@u@d@u@f@g@h@JjA`@nA^pAf@nAd@bAd@x@f@jAb@|@f@dAd@r@t@lAr@fAh@z@p@bAjAvBp@~@r@fAn@jAd@vAVjA\\|AXpA\\fB^bB`@bBh@~B^`B\\bBZ`B\\~AXlA\\~AXjAZ`BVlAZxAd@~BZ|AZzA\\xA\\vAVdAXrAV|@Nx@[f@s@c@uAz@m@`@u@l@o@b@m@j@k@h@u@p@q@t@k@n@q@r@m@t@kArAq@b@o@PCv@IL?CA@?@???@?A@?A?@C?@?@??????????????????????ALIJSXU`@]j@U`@Wb@[l@[j@]n@[l@U`@Sd@[l@Wl@Wj@Ub@Sh@[r@g@nAUf@Yn@Un@Yx@Ur@Sl@Qj@Sp@Oh@St@Wx@Sx@Ol@Od@Or@Qr@Qv@Qx@Qt@Q|@Oz@Mp@QbAMt@M|@Mz@Ir@M~@Kr@Ix@Kx@Gj@Kl@Kr@MfAKx@M~@M|@Ov@Kn@Kn@Mx@Ox@Ih@I\\BC???ACGBWFe@Ha@Ji@Ho@Jo@Jq@N{@RqAHo@L}@Ju@L{@Hw@Hm@Ho@Ly@L_AJ{@Jw@L_ANeALs@Jm@N{@Lm@Ny@Nw@P{@Nu@Nm@ZoANk@Ru@Rs@Tu@V}@Vw@Tw@Vq@Rm@Pk@Vs@Zu@Zw@Tk@Ve@Xq@Xo@Zq@Vg@Te@Vi@Vg@\\o@\\m@Xi@Xe@^q@\\g@Ta@Xe@X]H]?BEBC??@AA@@??A?A???????@??A@A??CD@G?@???@??????@@?A@@BM@K?A??B??BBA@B??@A?@?A??@????A?@D??AABAA??A@?A?@???A?@A????@A?@AA??@@@????D@CAA????????????????????????????????????A??????@???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????@?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????NNx@M^j@T?@[AA?@?MFC?A?A?????BA@??@???????????????????????????@S?A?????@????????????????@DCHGPGp@Sm@SU]BUNYMSRKR??A@A?????????????????DBRc@XCh@Kd@NVp@Fg@@_@A?BI???@????????????B?A?@AA??@??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????B?F?PW`@c@h@i@h@g@x@w@f@e@d@_@DC??@???A@TUd@_@x@i@~@o@t@c@bAo@z@e@n@_@d@`AZlAd@tBXpAXjATtATnATjAJdALjAN~@PnALbABlAA`@Gp@GdA\\`ANbAr@Nx@Ij@y@z@c@z@K~@GzAI`AI`@DFs@b@Kr@Iv@Cr@QbAK`A@dA?dBNr@h@LjANhBNdBNfBLhBN`BLzAN|ATrAn@Ar@_@j@Yv@g@z@c@n@SVjARlAJn@l@[t@c@lAk@\\x@N`AN|@RnARhANhARjAPdANt@HZBLA@???LJLZV^X\\R\\TVR\\ZFEYSc@SUW?Hb@\\`@\\b@^VT??????????????@I_@_@Fw@Pk@`@QT[WTNQK{@SgASaAQo@Q_AO_AKu@G@HLJd@@L?BDRJb@Jf@Nl@Nz@Px@Jr@Nh@f@QRKPOPMRI\\Q^S`@Uh@Uh@]RGA??A??A@OJ_@Pg@Vg@Vg@Xi@Zg@V{@^Sy@UmAUmAUgAUmAU_ABe@Pq@T_@J@HBA??@?????@FF@??A?B???AI?EDA@??@E@C???A??@?F?@B@B@??AA?DA?A????F??B???@??@?B?ACSG_@EMX?@ELMb@IZ?LNLH\\Hp@Jz@Rn@Nx@RdAP|@?f@BF^W^RPjAPbAPjAPlATtAN`ALx@K|@e@Hm@TEpAJ`BHjBHfBD|AH|AH|ADxAFpBJzAHnADrA@vA?hABzABjAFvAFtADzABlABxAFnAHfA@tA@xADvABrAB~ADxAKdAWn@k@HWz@FnADfAFvADpAHvA?~AHbBn@Pz@E~@El@MHB??AC@I?@?@B@ABA@?@?A???????????B@A?@CCIC]Da@Fg@B_@@g@D_@KIaAEcACkACaAKgBGyAGyAOkAI{@e@Cy@Fq@H_AD_ADw@BkAFm@Cu@ASSCA??[Ba@CS}@KiADq@@A?A??????BUe@[_AFcATaAp@_Ax@iAx@eAl@aAn@eAj@_Ap@u@^{@d@aAj@m@^s@Li@i@k@FWr@QbAi@^o@Zq@v@w@d@o@r@w@b@w@h@{@j@oAt@w@j@u@d@w@d@w@d@w@h@o@d@q@`@o@h@}@l@y@l@iAz@q@j@w@f@u@l@w@j@u@f@y@l@y@j@}@l@aAp@y@t@cA`Am@j@{@n@y@f@{@j@{@n@w@l@y@j@w@l@y@j@{@n@oA|@o@d@o@f@k@b@u@f@i@b@s@f@g@b@s@j@m@d@o@j@e@T]Z]Da@e@c@u@]m@Mq@W?IG??A???GNDn@If@QZC@@AA?EM?A???@??BFA?@@A@@A???????????@B@????AB?AGPUZa@b@k@l@m@p@c@f@o@r@g@f@m@r@q@x@q@x@g@n@q@p@k@j@o@v@e@j@eAlAg@j@q@r@q@r@g@j@q@v@i@l@o@r@m@v@s@v@q@r@mAtAe@l@o@v@i@l@w@x@y@~@{@|@{@`A_AdA_AfAu@rAk@lCGrBFlBHpBJlB?nBMtA[pAm@nAq@dAi@p@oA~As@bAu@bAm@~@a@t@Ph@d@n@j@r@f@n@b@f@h@p@l@v@h@p@d@f@l@d@h@Xj@Tr@Tt@Tt@Tv@Vv@T`Bf@|@Vx@Vv@Tx@Tx@Nx@N~@N~@Hx@Nz@Hb@z@FbBDfBFxAElBUpBSzAYlBa@hBa@fBSrAK`DBrBBpBFpB@tB?pBDdBFrAD\\?T???@??B^D`ABRHEJCDDHd@V\\Xb@LDA@AACK??A???ACAK?KFA@?AA@B@@@B?@?A@?AG@A???@????????????CDAAAG?ABD?@@@?B?B?????@??@?@?A@????????????@???ACAG?A??AC???@?@?@?B???AAC?@A@@@@??AA????A????B?BA?DAC??D?DA@??????@???????@CB?@??CAE?AA??C?@??@@?@AAA?B?B?B@????AAAEF??ALEA@ADDD@??AA??@?AB??@B?@xWzY\\I\\Od@Q\\Mn@Ut@Yv@Wv@[t@Yv@SpAk@x@Wp@Wh@Ux@Y~@_@`AY`AQ~@Q|@S`AUdAMdAKhAIhAM|@CFlADfBDnBDxADfBHxANzCHzAFnALz@DnAJtA@tAm@`@i@Fk@?_@F]f@WTSh@Q`@a@Vc@\\a@HUQQSUU_@Ss@Bg@Ji@Jc@HWFSHODUH[P[Fa@Ha@BW@OJQJYTS^MPCBA?@?????A???@A????@?A@?@????GB@CCBG?GBKF?LFPALQBODSPMNMPKTKNKTGPGXIRGP?RCDENCF?RALGRGTQFQDG@Q?SAQCM@OLGPIPOFOBKAGC?AA?B?DBB?IAB?LEJEHCJCDC@EDOLKJCN@N@PDL?LAJANEBC?Q@S?SBQBSHSBYFWHQDQHSJWJSJOLMJOLMJCJIH?HABA?EEECSDM@?BADEDABAFC@B@?A??????@@B???@AA?@?A@C?AFEJOP]TQTOXMX?ZE`@E^Ob@Qd@Sh@K^I`@G`@Kh@Gj@Zh@h@b@Nn@a@h@c@Zy@f@u@v@Yl@@n@Ob@[?{@GiAGcAEs@G_AIiAIkAGoAIyAG{ACqAEkACkACcAAcAA}@Bo@ZMb@KFCIa@`@?p@Gl@Gl@G|@Il@Gt@Cl@Ar@Ev@Yj@Uf@[l@Ip@Kp@Gr@Lt@Er@Kr@Bl@Dl@Aj@Ol@Qj@Un@_@x@a@t@c@l@a@p@a@`Ac@vA[t@{@^c@BOCSC[Em@Q}@MgAGkAEaALq@b@g@Li@O}@OcAS_AQ_AO{@Mg@@GAGAGEMCE@Gb@SDG?GAGAI?EFEZWd@FZc@XKf@^j@Nf@a@h@a@b@e@^e@`@i@j@k@\\]^g@l@u@?_A[m@ST_@r@]p@GD@AC?AC@?@A??@@???????????AAEJIFN@@@@C@?BA??????????????????@C?A@G@C?@A?@?@????????A@?@???CAA?A?@???CBC@???@???A@?A????????????????????????????AICCA?@B?@@@?????????????@????????????????????????????@?AA????????????@@??");

  var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: decodedPath,
    map: map
  });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < polyline.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
    bounds.extend(polyline.getPath().getAt(i));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```